Historical account state
Is it possible to see account data before or after a specific transaction in the recent past? I have a node with snapshots and everything, but how do I do that? The ledger tool doc seems to require a deeper understanding than I have.

You can start with some basic commands by running agave-ledger-tool -h. Specifically, you might want to start with the accounts subcommand:
$ agave-ledger-tool accounts -h
Print account stats and contents after processing the ledger

USAGE:
    agave-ledger-tool accounts [OPTIONS]

OPTIONS:
        --account <PUBKEY>...
            Limit output to accounts corresponding to the specified pubkey(s), may be specified multiple times

Looking at some of the other options, you likely want to copy your snapshot into some other directory and then run something like:
$ agave-ledger-tool accounts --account <PUBKEY_YOU_CARE_ABOUT> --snapshots <DIR>


Thank you very much for responding! I switched to a different thing for now, but I will get back to this later and try.
